# How to search a pattern from a file/String in Haskell

Tags: search, haskell

**  old**

Suppose we have a pattern ex. `"1101000111001110"`.
Now I have a pattern to be searched ex. `"1101"`. I am new to Haskell world, I am trying it at my end. I am able to do it in [c](/questions/tagged/c) but need to do it in Haskell.

Given Pattern := `"1101000111001110"`

Pattern To Be Searched :- `"110
Desired Output:-`"Pattern Found"`

** New**

```
import Data.List (isInfixOf)

main = do x <- readFile "read.txt"
      putStr x

isSubb :: [Char] -> [Char] -> Bool
isSubb sub str = isInfixOf sub str
```

This code reads a file named "read", which contains the following string 110100001101. Using isInfixOf you can check the pattern "1101" in the string and result will be True.

But the problem is  i am not able to search "1101" in the string present in "read.txt".
I need to compare the "read.txt" string with the user provided string. i.e

one string is their in the file "read.txt" 
and second string user will provid (user defined) and we will perform search and find whether user defined string is present in the string present in "read.txt"

Comment: What do you mean by "finding a binary pattern"?

Comment: @ThreeFx suppose a file contains only 0s 1s ex. 11011011110. Now i have to search a pattern ex. "1101" in that file.

Comment: @Spade why don't you expand your question to put some sample input and output for your expected problem. Also, it would be nice if you can say what you have tried so far and where you are stuck ?

Comment: Your pattern looks binary, but it's actually a `String` pattern, which happens to also be a `List`.

Comment: Oh, and please format your code properly.

Comment: @didierc whats wrong with the code format. To my knowledge it's  format is correct.

Comment: Now that you've edited it, sure it looks better. Something else for you to ponder about since you're new here (welcome btw): people are expected to now at least a little about the topic they wish to ask questions about. The reason is that we mainly focus on helping *fixing* issues, as opposed to *solving* problems. Please have a look at the FAQ.

Comment: @didierc I understand what you mean to say. That's why I have put my c code here. I have already gone through the FAQ.

Comment: What I mean is that you're supposed to have tried using *Haskell*, because that's the main topic here. I guess you got a downvote because of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to new:

To achieve this, you have to use `readLn`:

```
sub <- readLn
```

`readLn` accepts input until a `\n` is encountered and `<-` binds the result to `sub`. Watch out that if the input should be a string you have to explicitly type the `"`s around your string.

Alternatively if you do not feel like typing the quotation marks every time, you can use `getLine` in place of `readLn` which has the type `IO String` which becomes `String` after being bound to `sub`

For further information on all functions included in the standard libraries of Haskell see [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/). Using Hoogle you can search functions by various criteria and will often find functions which suit your needs.

---

Answer to old:

Use the `isInfixOf` function from `Data.List` to search for the pattern:

```
import Data.List (isInfixOf)

isInfixOf "1101" "1101000111001110" -- outputs true
```

It returns true if the first sequence exists in the second and false otherwise.

To read a file and get its contents use `readFile`:

```
contents <- readFile "filename.txt"
```

You will get the whole file as one string, which you can now perform standard functions on.

Outputting `"Pattern found"` should be trivial then.

Comment: Let me try this. Thanks ThreeFx.

Comment: @Spade If it worked, please accept the answer to help others who have the same problem

Comment: I have implemented what you said.But it only cover half part, we need to fix the other half also.

Comment: @Spade What do you mean with the "other part"? Sorry just saw it

Comment: I have included the problem above.See thing is one string is there in the file "read.txt" and second string will be provided by the user (user defined) and we will be perform search and find whether the user string is present in the file "read.txt" string.This is the other part.